# Pydatalog, Can't print right side of rules

Tags: logic-programming, pydatalog

Following my last post with no answer,
and because I'm stuck by this
(by the way I have other question =I don't know if Pydatalog conceptor,Mr Carbonnelle, is still answerring on this site ??)
So it would be nice if someone can help,
and I will try to be more clear:

See part of my code below:

```
from pyDatalog import pyDatalog
pyDatalog.create_terms('condition, predicate, yes, X')

+condition('a')
+condition('b')
+condition('c')
+condition('d')

predicate('p1')<=yes('a') & yes('b')
predicate('p2')<= yes('c') & yes('d')
```

**problem** : If I Know conclusion 'p1', How can I get/print 'a' and 'b' ?
I don't know how to do that ?
(print('p1') doesn't work at all!!)
Thanks for help

Jeangil

Answer (score 1):

there is no connection between your dataset and your prediction (as I do not see any logic in your conditions - they are just true statements / strings). I slightly modified your code to show the logic of a working example (hope this answers your questions or gives you a hint for a solution):

```
from pyDatalog import pyDatalog
pyDatalog.create_terms('condition, predicate, yes, X')

+condition('a', 1)
+condition('a', 2)
+condition('c', 3)
+condition('d', 4)

print(condition(X,1))
print(condition('a',X))
```